# Why can't I call an inherited public method without prefacing it with a reference from main method?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have below classes in the same package:

```
class Roo {
    public String doRooThings()
    {
        return "Rooing!";
    }
}

class Cloo extends Roo {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(doRooThings());
    }
}
```

I get **Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method doRooThings() from the type Roo** error upon executing this.

But I can call the **doRooThings()** method (without having to preface it with a reference) from a public method in child class **like below** :

```
class Cloo extends Roo {
    public void testRoo()
    {
        System.out.println(doRooThings());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Cloo().testRoo();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know how this works?

Comment: You do realise that you are creating a reference in the second case. "new Cloo()". Your statement itself "without having to preface it with a reference" is incorrect here. Perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: Your main() is static, meaning it doesn't have access to any instance variables.  Maybe reading this would help to explain what static means: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first case **main method is static** and method **doRooThings()** this non static method. Inside static method you can't refer a non-static (instance) method.

But in second case you are able to call non static method testRoo() because your creating an instance within the static context. Similarly even in first case you call the non static method by creating instance as like below:

**new Roo().doRooThings()** or **new Cloo().doRooThings()**

Answer (score 2):

Because the `main()` method runs in a `static` context. Static means you have no valid instance of the class. That means Java doesn't know which instance to call that method on...

Read some basics like [this explanation](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-the-static-keyword-in-java.html).

Answer (score 2):

`main` is a static method, therefor it is not associated with any instance of the class. As a result it can not call an instance method(as it needs to be associated with an instance) unless it first creates an instance. Maybe you need to read more about the [meaning of static](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413904/812912)?

Comment: I am creating an instance of    Cloo in main method. So, Does that mean this instance will be shared throughout the class?

Answer (score 1):

Because your method `doRooThings` is not static while your main method is a static. you can call doRooThings by 2 options:

## First

create an object of Roo on your main method  `Roo roo = new Roo();` then call it by `roo.doRooThings();`

## Second

change your method `doRooThings()` to static, `public static void doRooThings();`

## Additional

if we create a static method or an static instance variable  it means that it is owned by that class.

on your `new Cloo().testRoo();` you are able to call the `testRoo()` method because you created a new instance of `Cloo` class by having a `new` keyword. it is the same of my first suggestion the only difference was on my first suggestion I create a new instance of `Roo` class and reference it to `roo`